# How do I add error checking to my VBA file copy macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add error handling to this. Basically this code looks at a source folder that has 15000 JPEG images and compares it to column A, and copies the file names listed in Column A from A1 down into a destination folder, and it works but I have no error handling. It would be nice to know which files don't copy because they're misnamed, so I can fix the holes in my data.

Is there any way I can add error checking and have it turn the cells red if the image file in the sourcepath doesn't exist?

```
Sub test()
Dim r As Range
Dim sourcepath As String, destpath As String, fname As String
sourcepath = "C:\Users\paul\Desktop\CONVERTED TIFS\"
destpath = "c:\test2\"


For Each r In Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    fname = Dir(sourcepath & r)
    Do While fname <> ""
        FileCopy sourcepath & fname, destpath & fname
        fname = Dir()
Loop
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You have loop for each filename - do you expect more than one match per cell in Col A?

Comment: It should be one match per cell. Each cell in column A is one file name "\image1.jpg" "\image2.jpg" etc etc. If "\image3.jpg" isn't in my destination folder, I need to figure out how to make that cell a different color so I can remedy the holes in my data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Sub test()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim sourcepath As String, destpath As String, fname As String

    sourcepath = "C:\Users\paul\Desktop\CONVERTED TIFS\"
    destpath = "c:\test2\"

    For Each r In Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If len(r.value) > 0 then
            fname = Dir(sourcepath & r.Value)

            If Len(fname) > 0 Then
                r.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                r.offset(0, 1).Value = "Copied"
                FileCopy sourcepath & fname, destpath & fname
            Else
                r.Interior.Color = vbRed
                r.offset(0, 1).Value = "Not found"
            End If

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Adjust the offset if you want to put the tracking into a different column.

Comment: you're the man. the len function is something i never knew about. thanks for sharing the knowledge.